# Server side Loop to Client Side Array

Tags: javascript, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assign Vb.net loop variable values to javascript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666402/assign-vb-net-loop-variable-values-to-javascript-array)

I have server side loop of DB Values and i want to pass them in Client side Array
My server side code is bellow

```
 Dim GPS As New String("")
        Dim STATION As new String("")
        For I = 0 To ds.Tables("GPS").Rows.Count - 1
            I = ds.Tables("GPS").Rows.Count - 1
            GPS = ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("GPS_ONE")
            STATION = ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("STA_NAME")
        Next I
```

And Client side array is

```
 store_locations = [ 
        new google.maps.LatLng(31.204549793299,72.264183974237),
        new google.maps.LatLng(31.23004996385,72.282225091978),
        new google.maps.LatLng(31.148218,72.224542),
        new google.maps.LatLng(31.2330555556,72.3330555556)
        ];

     for(i=0; i<store_locations.length; i++)
        {
              markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker(
              { 
               position: store_locations[i],
               map: map,
               draggable:true,
               icon:image,
               title: 'ADEEL' + (i+1)
               });                       
        }
```

Now here i want to get store_locations from Server side GPS variable.Is there any way to pass the server side GPS into Client store_location so that all values of GPS coming from loop should assign to array.

I have done some thing here to do but fail

```
 var GPS = '<%=GPS %>'.replace(/ /g, '').split(',');
GPS_AR = new array();
GPS_AR = [
new google.maps.LatLng(GPS[0], GPS[1])
    ];
```